# Can we run two applications in a embedded device simultaneously

Tags: linux

just curious if we can run two applications (any sample applications) in a embedded device (lets say imx6) simultaneously, as generally we have only one serial console to access the target?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you want to do?

Comment: If I did not misunderstand this [link](http://superuser.com/questions/463138/how-to-run-two-commands-simultaneously) will help you.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I want to run two applications on an imx6 board, which is running Linux OS. Is it possible? as i see (generally) only one serial console to access the imx6 device.

Comment: Of course, assuming of course there are adequate resources (memory, CPU context) to run them.